# How to get value of HTML element with VB.net

Tags: html, asp.net, textbox, server-side

I create html element from database :

```
Dim table As String = "<form method='POST'>"
table &= "<input type='textbox' value='123' id='txtText'/>"
table &= "<input type="sumbit" text='Submit' /></form>"
```

When i click button submit, I want get value textbox with VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `RUNAT = "SERVER"`

```
<form method='POST'>
   <input type='textbox' value='123' id='txtText'/>
   <input runat="SERVER" type="hidden" name="txtHidden" value="123" />
</form>
```

You need to set the value to hidden text, use `runat = "SERVER"`and get the value on server-side.

Comment: How to get value ? I have use code Request("txtText") is Nothing ?

Comment: `txtText` will be visible in server side, then you can use `txtText.Value`

Comment: txtText is not declared. I create form html by String vb.net

Comment: Yes, I create html element from infor database

Comment: Could you update the question informing the server-side code please?

Comment: Did you add the `runat="SERVER"` as I suggested?

Comment: Yes, I have added and get error "txtText is not declared"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57799/discussion-between-nizam-and-user1761176).